# Find closest point on mesh to other point in Threejs?

Tags: three.js, 3d

Hello StackOverflow community! I have a point in my scene floating around and a complex group of meshes. I need to find the closest point on any of these meshes to the original point. I think I could do this with something like a SphereCast but I haven't found any in Threejs docs.

Here is a 2D representation of what I need to do:

[image]

Basically, I have P1 and and all the other surfaces in a group, and I need to find P2.

Thanks you!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you discounting brute-force search?

Comment: Nope! totally an option! This event is only going to be fired onClick when the user clicks on a surface, so it's cheap to do it by brute-force. But I', not clear how :(

Comment: One other thing to consider, and it's another point of clarification, are you looking for the closest _vertex_ of the mesh, or are you seeking a purely mathematical point on the surface of the mesh? The difference being the former would brute-force the vertices of the mesh, but might result in ties or not quite represent the absolute "nearest point" due to triangles representing curved surfaces. The later is, as you might expect, harder/more expensive to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems you want to reproduce what's implemented in ray casting. But I think it depends on the shape you consider in your example, because you would need the equation of the surface to get an analytical solution.

I found [this example](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection) of ray casting for basic shapes (spheres, triangle, etc.), but there is no general solutions without the shape's equations. 
For instance, for ray-sphere intersection, they give the following C++  :

```
{ 
        float t0, t1; // solutions for t if the ray intersects 
#if 0 
        // geometric solution
        Vec3f L = center - orig; 
        float tca = L.dotProduct(dir); 
        // if (tca < 0) return false;
        float d2 = L.dotProduct(L) - tca * tca; 
        if (d2 > radius2) return false; 
        float thc = sqrt(radius2 - d2); 
        t0 = tca - thc; 
        t1 = tca + thc; 
#else 
        // analytic solution
        Vec3f L = orig - center; 
        float a = dir.dotProduct(dir); 
        float b = 2 * dir.dotProduct(L); 
        float c = L.dotProduct(L) - radius2; 
        if (!solveQuadratic(a, b, c, t0, t1)) return false; 
#endif 
        if (t0 > t1) std::swap(t0, t1); 

        if (t0 < 0) { 
            t0 = t1; // if t0 is negative, let's use t1 instead 
            if (t0 < 0) return false; // both t0 and t1 are negative 
        } 

        t = t0; 

        return true; 
}
```

I think that in Three.js, because most materials are composed of small triangles, every ray casting calculus relies on a triangle ray casting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting links, please always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer